# Comments for Documenting XML Entities

Tags: xml, dtd

I've seen people documenting XML entities with comments before the entity definition:

```
<DOCTYPE root
[
<!-- Some Documentation here --> <!ENTITY foo "bar">
]>
```

In some editors (e.g. Oxygen XML), when hovering over the entity, the documentation would be displayed in a popup window.

This behaviour seems very reasonable to me. However I could not find any information, if that is officially how entities are documented or if that's just how some people do it.
Is there any (maybe even W3C) authoritativ document on how entities should be documented?

Comment: Do web search for "rfc xml specification"

Comment: @jdweng: Searching for those terms quoted yields only 7 results, none of which appear to be authoritative.  Do you have a prefered link?  Thank you.

Comment: A quick search revealed [W3C XML Specification DTD (“XMLspec”)](https://www.w3.org/XML/1998/06/xmlspec-report-19980910.htm). Maybe this link is of some help for you.

Comment: Try https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/ which a beginning says : Note: On 7 February 2013, this specification was modified in place to replace broken links to RFC4646 and RFC4647.

Comment: @jdweng: I guess I'm still confused.  You were attempting to refer OP to the W3C XML Recommendation in general to answer a question about whether there are any conventions for documenting XML entity declarations?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Maybe I'm missing something here, but in neither of the links referenced did I find an explicit section on how to use comments to document entities. However in both documents it is done like I observed before: The Comment directly preceding the entity is used to document this entity. So I'll just assume that's how it's done.